CSS Position Sticky to preview content of next div
I am trying to create a floating preview of the content that follows the current part of the page being scrolled. It may be easier to explain with code.
We have the current content.
<div class="current-content">
  <p>hi 1</p>
    <p>hi 2</p>
    <p>hi 3</p>
    <p>hi 4</p>
    <p>hi 5</p>
    <p>hi 6</p>
    <p>hi 7</p>
    <p>hi 8</p>
    <p>hi 9</p>
</div>

After that we have some more content.
<div class="next-content">
  <p>hi 1</p>
    <p>hi 2</p>
    <p>hi 3</p>
    <p>hi 4</p>
    <p>hi 5</p>
    <p>hi 6</p>
    <p>hi 7</p>
    <p>hi 8</p>
    <p>hi 9</p>
</div>

The idea is that whilst we are scrolling the page from the top, we scroll through current content, but next content occupies 50% of the viewport using position sticky until it is scrolled into view.
p {
  font-size: 28px;
  marin: 20px;
}

.current-content {
  background: yellow;
}

.next-content {
  background: pink;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: -50vh;
}

The problem is, that this does not appear to be possible using top because next-content appears after current-content in the HTML tree. Therefore it can only be accomplished using bottom. The problem is, that bottom is a reference to the bottom position of next-content relative to the viewport and therefore without knowing the height of next-content there is no way to make it fill only 50% of the viewport whilst stuck.
I hope that makes sense, and is there a way to achieve this.
For context, think of a news website where you directly scroll from one article to the the next article but whilst scrolling, there is always a preview of what the next article will be that will scroll into view once you get there.


p {
  font-size: 28px;
  marin: 20px;
}

.current-content {
  background: yellow;
}

.next-content {
  background: pink;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: -100%; // set to -100% for demonstration purposes
}
<body>
  <div class="current-content">
    <p>hi 1</p>
    <p>hi 2</p>
    <p>hi 3</p>
    <p>hi 4</p>
    <p>hi 5</p>
    <p>hi 6</p>
    <p>hi 7</p>
    <p>hi 8</p>
    <p>hi 9</p>
  </div>
  <div class="next-content">
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
  </div>
</body>




For pure CSS I only have a way over complicated solution with multiple limitations which probably shouldn't be used in production. The intuition is to use make current-content itself 50vh and allow overflow:scroll on it as well. By this way the next div will be natually placed at the middle. This itself is very easy to implement.


p {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.current-content {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.next-content {
  background: pink;
}
<div class="current-content">
  <p>start1</p>
  <p>hi 2</p>
  <p>hi 3</p>
  <p>hi 4</p>
  <p>hi 5</p>
  <p>hi 6</p>
  <p>hi 7</p>
  <p>hi 1</p>
  <p>hi 2</p>
  <p>hi 3</p>
  <p>hi 4</p>
  <p>hi 5</p>
  <p>hi 6</p>
  <p>hi 7</p>
  <p>hi 1</p>
  <p>hi 2</p>
  <p>hi 3</p>
  <p>hi 4</p>
  <p>hi 5</p>
  <p>hi 6</p>
  <p>hi 7</p>
  <p>hi 1</p>
  <p>hi 2</p>
  <p>hi 3</p>
  <p>hi 4</p>
  <p>hi 5</p>
  <p>hi 6</p>
  <p>hi 7</p>
  <p>hi 1</p>
  <p>hi 2</p>
  <p>hi 3</p>
  <p>hi 4</p>
  <p>hi 5</p>
  <p>hi 6</p>
  <p>hi 7</p>
  <p>hi 1</p>
  <p>hi 2</p>
  <p>hi 3</p>
  <p>hi 4</p>
  <p>hi 5</p>
  <p>hi 6</p>
  <p>hi 7</p>
  <p>hi 1</p>
  <p>hi 2</p>
  <p>hi 3</p>
  <p>hi 4</p>
  <p>hi 5</p>
  <p>hi 6</p>
  <p>hi 7</p>
  <p>hi 8</p>
  <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">end1</p>
</div>
<div class="next-content">
  <p style="margin-top: 0px;">start2</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>end2</p>
</div>



However, as you can see this is not desired because it will create two scrollbars for both current-content and the parent container.
The idea is to use animation-timeline:scroll(y) to detect if the next-content div is reached and should start scrolling. In current-content a pseudo element that covers the parent container is created, so current-content can be scrolled wherever the user is scrolling within the parent container before next-content is reached. When it reaches the end, the parent container's scrollbar then can natually be moved. This triggers the animation-timeline to start, which adjusts the z-index to make next-content above the covering pseudo-element, so that next-content can be scrolled instead.
However, there is one main limitation of this solution: since this solution breaks the natural single scroll of a page, most likely the scrollbars should be hidden. Hence, when scrolling the top div the visible scrollbar won't be moving.
Another pretty big limitation is that animation-timeline isn’t widely supported and wouldn’t work on mobiles because of how scroll chaining/overscroll works differently.


p {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 20px;
}


/*Not required but since there are childs using z-index, I would wrap it under a new stacking context*/
.wrapper {
  isolation: isolate;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.current-content {
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.content-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  top: 50vh;
}

.next-content {
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  top: -50vh;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-clip: content-box;
  animation: offset-next 1ms linear both;
  animation-timeline: scroll(y);
}

@keyframes offset-next {
  from {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  0.01% {
    padding-top: 50vh;
    top: -100vh;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  to {
    padding-top: 50vh;
    top: -100vh;
    z-index: 3;
  }
}
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class="current-content">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p>start1</p>
      <p>hi 2</p>
      <p>hi 3</p>
      <p>hi 4</p>
      <p>hi 5</p>
      <p>hi 6</p>
      <p>hi 7</p>
      <p>hi 1</p>
      <p>hi 2</p>
      <p>hi 3</p>
      <p>hi 4</p>
      <p>hi 5</p>
      <p>hi 6</p>
      <p>hi 7</p>
      <p>hi 1</p>
      <p>hi 2</p>
      <p>hi 3</p>
      <p>hi 4</p>
      <p>hi 5</p>
      <p>hi 6</p>
      <p>hi 7</p>
      <p>hi 1</p>
      <p>hi 2</p>
      <p>hi 3</p>
      <p>hi 4</p>
      <p>hi 5</p>
      <p>hi 6</p>
      <p>hi 7</p>
      <p>hi 1</p>
      <p>hi 2</p>
      <p>hi 3</p>
      <p>hi 4</p>
      <p>hi 5</p>
      <p>hi 6</p>
      <p>hi 7</p>
      <p>hi 1</p>
      <p>hi 2</p>
      <p>hi 3</p>
      <p>hi 4</p>
      <p>hi 5</p>
      <p>hi 6</p>
      <p>hi 7</p>
      <p>hi 1</p>
      <p>hi 2</p>
      <p>hi 3</p>
      <p>hi 4</p>
      <p>hi 5</p>
      <p>hi 6</p>
      <p>hi 7</p>
      <p>hi 8</p>
      <p style="margin-bottom: 0px">end1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next-content">
    <p style="margin-top: 0px">start2</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>hi</p>
    <p>end2</p>
  </div>
</div>




A most intriguing approach but as you point out yourself, it's over engineered and not widely supported whilst breaking the single scroll of a page. An approach I have gone for is to use the bottom value initially and then use javascript to remove that value, and use a combination of top and transform:translate to mimic the situation. Then add a scroll listener to undo the change to top and transform at a certain scroll position.

Yeah shouldn't be used in production for sure haha. I was waiting a few days to see if there are some obvious easy CSS solutions that I've missed, but seems not. In this case JS solution is probably the best.
